# How to enumerate nested classes in python?

Tags: python, nested, inner-classes

How to implement function, which enumerate nested classes?

```py
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        pass

    class C(object):
        pass


def enumerate_nested_classes(_class):
    return ()  # need proper implementation instead


assert set(enumerate_nested_classes(A)) == {A.B, A.C}
```

Comment: Does it need to be recursive?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve?!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the next code:

```
import types


class A(object):
    class B(object):
        pass

    class C(object):
        pass

def enumerate_nested_classes(_class):
    return [getattr(_class, n) for n in dir(_class) if not n.startswith('__')
            and isinstance(getattr(_class, n), (type, types.ClassType))] 

assert enumerate_nested_classes(A) == [A.B, A.C]
```

And `print enumerate_nested_classes(A)` prints `[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]`

NB. `dir(_class)` resulting list is sorted alphabetically, so when using `assert enumerate_nested_classes(A) == [A.B, A.C]` it is better to use:  `assert sorted(enumerate_nested_classes(A)) == sorted([A.B, A.C])`.

Comment: It's so simple and works even without importing `inspect`.
One more variant of this: `(n for n in (getattr(_class, n) for n in dir(_class) if not n.startswith('__')) if isinstance(n, (type, types.ClassType)))`

Answer (score 7):

[`inspect.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) in conjunction with [`inspect.isclass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) should help here:

```
classes = [name for name, member_type in inspect.getmembers(A)
           if inspect.isclass(member_type) and not name.startswith("__")]

print(classes)  # prints ['B', 'C']
```

<sup>Note that `not name.startswith("__")` check is needed to exclude `__class__` - I suspect there is a simpler and a more pythonic way to do so, would appreciate if somebody would point that out.</sup>

Comment: Output should be `[getattr(A, name) for name in classes]` though.  Also I don't believe this will get further nested ones ..

Comment: @wim thanks, yes, this is not recursive at the moment, let's see if the OP would need to go deeper.